# Submit button with POST instead of using HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form inside a form and this makes the top form unresponsive. When I take off the second form (which is inside the first form), the first form works. This is the second form I have:

```
<form action="imgupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h3>Upload a new image:</h3>
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
            <br>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['Gallery_Id']; ?>" name="gid">
            <input type="hidden" value="User" name="user">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="imgup">
</form>
```

Since this makes the first form not work, I was wondering if I can take off the form fields and then the submit button can send the form data to the `imgupload.php` like this.

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['Gallery_Id']; ?>" name="gid">
<input type="hidden" value="User" name="user">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="imgup" action="imgupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This does not work now. Is there a way I can get this working? If not, what's an alternative way to send this data to the other php?

Comment: Why do you need a form within a form? Why use two php documents if you are combining the two forms?

Comment: The two forms are not combined. I'm looping some stuff from a database and these input forms should come together inside the loop. The first form posts the data to the same file (newsearch.php) and the second form posts the data to `imgupload.php`.

Comment: Why not either combine the two forms and merge the php documents, or place one form after the other. It makes no sense to put <form> tags's within other <form> tags.

Comment: @Ethernetz, oh wow why didn't I think of this?! That worked. Thank you very much

Comment: You are only showing us one form, and it's a file upload system. I am trying to imagine what the second form does. Are you requesting additional data from the user? Sounds kinda like you should be using `input` fields within a DIV structure, and using js/jQuery to grab those values when the form is submitted. Really, though, it sounds like you should check out [AJAX - it's pretty simple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025289/prevent-page-load-on-jquery-form-submit-with-none-display-button#36025530) and hella useful.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are uploading files, have a look at Ravi Kusuma's [Hayageek jQuery File Upload plugin](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php).  It's simple, it's a Swiss Army Knife, and it works.

Study the examples.

http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

Ravi breaks down the process into three simple steps, that basically look like this:

```
<head>
    <link href="http://hayageek.github.io/jQuery-Upload-File/uploadfile.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  // (1)
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://hayageek.github.io/jQuery-Upload-File/jquery.uploadfile.min.js"></script>   // (1)
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fileuploader">Upload</div>  // (2)
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({  // (3)
                url:"my_php_processor.php",
                fileName:"myfile"
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

The final step is to have the PHP file specified in the jQuery code (in this case `my_php_processor.php`) to receive and process the file:

**my_php_processor.php:**

```
<?php
    $output_dir = "uploads/";
    $theFile = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);
```

*Note the relationship between `myfile` in the PHP (`$_FILES["myfile"]`), and the filename specified in the jQuery code block.*

Don't forget to check out the [server-side code](https://github.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file/blob/master/php/upload.php) from the `Server Side` tab -- you need both parts (js and php).

---

Looking at your question again, you will probably want to use this functionality as well:

```
dynamicFormData: function()
{
    var data ={ location:"INDIA"}
    return data;
}
```

or

```
dynamicFormData: function(){
    return {
        newID: $("#newNID").val(),
        newSubj: $("#newSubj").val(),
        newBody: $("#newBody").val(),
        formRole: $('#formRole').val()
    };
```

These will appear on the PHP side, thus:

```
$newID = $_POST['newID'];
$subj = $_POST['newSubj'];
etc
```

---

As with any plugin, resist the temptation to just plop it into your code. Do a couple of quick-and-dirty tests with it first. Kick its tires. *Fifteen minutes will save you two hours.*

And don't forget to verify what was uploaded. You never know when a developing country black hat might be trying to get a new account.