# Button for php function doesnt work after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am attempting to add, or subtract a pts field in a database based on if you press a button and then update the content on the page, I also have the fields that the pts are being display in , on a timer with `Ajax` to auto-refresh.

I am using this script to call the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var timer, delay = 1000;                // 1 second(s) counted in milliseconds
        var Pts = '';                          //ID value of users answer
        var info = {'userPts': Pts};           //naming POST for php
        timer = setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "inc/ans.php",            //sends to ans page where php function updates DB
                type: "POST",
                data : info,                   //stuff being sent to php
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $("div #ans").html(data);  //Retrieves answers made by user
                }
            });
        }, delay);
```

My issue is when I make this call the only way currently to click the buttons is to manually refresh the entire page and then I am able to click the buttons and update the users pts value. I am able to do one or the other but not at the same time, I can have it where it auto-refreshes the content but I can’t have the button press complete the action. And I can have the buttons be able to be pressed but I can’t have the content auto-refresh.

The `PHP` functions to add and subtract are about the same they are like this:

```
    function addPoint($mysqli, $id)
    {
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('
        UPDATE tbl_user 
        SET user_pts = user_pts + 1
        WHERE user_id = ?');
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->affected_rows; 
        $stmt->close();
        if($rows == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Only difference between the two functions is the fact that its -1 or +1. Any ideas on why this happens? Is it the `Ajax` call this is interfering with the `PHP` function or vic. versa?

**EDIT:** This is the code that is being displayed to the instructor with the buttons

```
    function getScore_I($mysqli)
    {
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('
        SELECT user_name, user_pts, user_id
        FROM tbl_user');
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($user, $pts, $id);
        $O ="";
        $x = 1;
        $O.="<table style=\"text-align:center;width: 100%\"><form action=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']." method=\"POST\">";
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
            if($x%2)
            {
                $O.= "<tr style=\"text-align:center;width: 100%\">
                        <td>".$user."</td>
                        <td>
                            <button name=\"userIDmiunus\" type=\"submit\" value=\"".$id."\">-</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>".$pts."</td>

                        <td>
                            <button name=\"userIDplus\" type=\"submit\" value=\"".$id."\">+</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>";
                $x++;
            }
            else
            {
                $O.= "<tr style=\"text-align:center;width: 100%\">
                        <td>".$user."</td>
                        <td>
                            <button name=\"userIDmiunus\" type=\"submit\" value=\"".$id."\">-</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>".$pts."</td>

                        <td>
                            <button name=\"userIDplus\" type=\"submit\" value=\"".$id."\">+</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>";
                $x++;
            }
        }
        $O.= "</form></table>";
        // close statement
        $stmt->close();
        return $O;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use timer?....Do you want to execute the php function via ajax when Clicked?...If Yes,try use the click event instead of timer.

Comment: I want to just have a fixed timer that will automatically update he page when an answer is added to the database or when a new pts value is assigned, in the instructor side , that superuser if you will, is the one asigning pts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it the case that the button elements are included in the code brought in via AJAX? If so, you need to use `.on()`, as in:

```
$(document).on('click', '.buttonClassName', function(){
    //do your click code here
});
```

Reviewing your code, it looks like you are just doing a `.load()`, which is a shortcut version of `$.ajax()`. *I also prefer using `$.ajax()` in all circumstances - use `$.load()`, `$.get()` and `$.post()` are not as well structured as the full `$.ajax()`*

When the new data is injected into the DOM via `.html()`, any controls are not bound to javascript code, since the binding code was run prior to their injection. Two solutions: you can also inject some additional javascript and recreate those bindings -- which means much duplicate code in the DOM -- or you can use `.on()` which works for the elements currently in the DOM, but also for all future elements injected into the DOM that have that specific class or ID or *whatever jQuery selector you use.*

Another possibility could be that you need to use AJAX to access your PHP function. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025289/prevent-page-load-on-jquery-form-submit-with-none-display-button#36025530) *and the post it references/links to* regarding AJAX. Check out the examples.

---

Yes, you can call another AJAX function inside the `.on(),` and that is probably what you need to do.

Recall that AJAX is just a method for running PHP code *after* the web page has been rendered, and without refreshing/leaving the current page.

Code could look something like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.buttonClass', function(){
    var Pts = '';                          //ID value of users answer
    var uid = $('hidden_input_where_you_stored_userID').val();
    var info = {'userID': uid, 'userPts': Pts};           //naming POST for php
    $.ajax({
        url: "inc/another_file.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : info,
        success: function(data) {
            //whatever you need to do after updating point score
        }
    });
});
```

**another_file.php:**

```
<?php
    $id =  $_POST['userID'];
    $pts = $_POST['userPts']; 
    //do your DB update
```

Comment: The buttons are part of the php that is being called by the ajax should ad that in the php function then?

Comment: So inside of that .on i can call another ajax function?

Comment: @Apparatus17 Yes, but `.load()` is a shortcut version of `$.ajax()` - I wanted to make sure you knew that. Also, the `.load()` really explains what part of AJAX you are using. Myself, I never use the shortcuts, I always use the full `$.ajax()` structure -- but I was using that reference to show you what you are using AJAX for, and to highlight the different way you would use AJAX inside the `.on()` code block.