# passing variable into Modal and Query Database

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, simplemodal

Trying to pass variable into a HTML modal, run a query and display info based on the id... I can pass the parameter into the HTML with this but I need it at the end of a SQL WHERE statement at the end of a query...

my script is here. Im thinking I need some ajax to accomplish this. I created a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rbla/y7s5tf3p/

```
<script>

$(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
 var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
 //$(".modal-body #bookId").val( myBookId );
 document.getElementById("bookId").innerHTML = myBookId; 

});

</script>
```

The variable gets inserted into the HTML , but I need to get the data-id into a php variable and not HTML so that I can run a query...

Here is the PHP file I have

```
<?php

$id = ( this is where the data-id needs to be );

$sql = oci_parse($conn, select * from movies m where id=:id");

oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':id', $id);

oci_execute($sql, OCI_DEFAULT);

$objResult = oci_fetch_array($sql);
?>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need AJAX to do what you want.

Note that `$(this).data('id')` will get the value of a tag attribute similar to:

```
<input type="text" data-id="mother" id="17" />
```

It would grab the value `mother`, not `17`.

This below code sample is probably similar to what you will need to build:

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
$(document).on("click", ".openSlickModal-1", function () {
    var myMovieId = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
         url: 'my_ajax_processor.php',
        data: 'MovieID=' +myMovieId,
        success: function(d){
            alert(d); ////Just for testing: disable after receiving the correct response
            $("#movie").html(d);
        }
    });

});
```

**my_ajax_processor.php:**

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST['MovieID'];
    die('Received: ' .$id); //Just a test: disable this after receiving the correct response

    //do your query using the $id
    $out = 'Whatever you create (HTML or plain text) after your query
    echo $out;
?>
```

---

Additional References:

[dynamic drop down box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924082/dynamic-drop-down-box/16924652#16924652)

[Prevent Page Load on Jquery Form Submit with None Display Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025289/prevent-page-load-on-jquery-form-submit-with-none-display-button#36025530)

Comment: I use this for my links that open the modals

Comment: <div class="openSlickModal-1 manualLabel" data-id="54">VIEW MOVIE</div>

Comment: Oh, okay then. Just a bit unusual, but perfectly acceptable. You can use either `id=` or `data-id=`, but `id=` is more common. Does the above code give you an idea how to proceed? *If you have further questions, please leave another comment.*

Comment: I just updated my entire question, added some php and created a jsfiddle. I tried what you said unsuccessfully. if you could assist - I would be appreciative...