# AJAX vs JS. difference when storing JS var value to a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have been reading some posts here regarding issues about storing values form JS to a PHP variable and most comments said to use AJAX.

both AJAX and JS codes can be used to store JS variable value to a PHP variable however can someone explain why most people suggest to use AJAX? or what advantages do I have if I used AJAX over JS to store that value

thanks

Comment: _storing values form JS to a PHP variable and most comments said to use AJAX_ .You've answer your own question, I guess.

Comment: You use AJAX when your page needs to get data without refreshing.

Comment: You can send a JSON object with multiple variables in a single request as @Jose Manuel Abarca Rodríguez said without refreshing. It's pretty easy to build a JSON object in JS and it's becoming a standard in data transfers.

Comment: Unless the data is sent on https, remember it is not secure.  PHP allows you to store a data object as a session variable, thereby restricting access to the session user.  This can be accomplished in JS as well, and is available in many frameworks.

Comment: You're a bit mixed up on what AJAX is. AJAX isn't a language or something separate from JavaScript. It's a means of sending data to a server. Think of it this way: You (JS) write a letter and stick it in an envelope with the address on it. The mailman (AJAX) gets it to its destination. You write JS that *uses* AJAX. You don't *replace* JS with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store a PHP value from javascript/jQuery *without* using AJAX.

After the DOM has been rendered, no additional PHP will run. That's it, all done. In order to send additional data to the server, you have two choices: (1) post a form to another PHP file, which will send the data typed into the form elements *and will change/refresh the current page.* or (2) use AJAX.

AJAX is a way to communicate with a separate PHP page, sending data back/forth, *without refreshing/changing the page the user is on.* An AJAX code block looks something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
     url: 'ajax.php',
    data: 'varName=' +varSomething,
    success: function(d){
        if (d.length) alert(d);
    }
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
     url: 'ajax.php',
    data: 'varSomename=' +varValue
}).done(function(){
    //success function
});
```

Data sent back from PHP is received in the AJAX code block's `success` function (and ONLY there), where it can be manipulated and/or injected back into the DOM, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
     url: 'ajax.php',
    data: 'thevar=' +theval,
    success: function(d){
        $('#someDIV').html(d);
    }
});
```

Here are some additional links re AJAX:

[dynamic drop down box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924082/dynamic-drop-down-box/16924652#16924652)

[Prevent Page Load on Jquery Form Submit with None Display Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025289/prevent-page-load-on-jquery-form-submit-with-none-display-button#36025530)

---

When the data arrives at the specified PHP file *(ajax.php in above examples),* you can get that data via the `$_POST[]` variable:

```
<?php
    $summat = $_POST['someVarname'];

    //To send data back to the AJAX success function, you just echo it:
    $out = '<div style="font-size:3rem;color:blue;">';
    $out .= $summat;
    $out .= '</div>';
    echo $out
```

Now you have the data in a local PHP variable. This variable will cease to exist when the PHP file execution is completed.
To retain the PHP variable, use a $_SESSION super-variable. In order to use the $_SESSION variable, you must add `session_start()` to the top of the PHP page:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['summat'] = $_POST['someVarname'];

    //Now you have a permanent variable on the server, associated with this user's PHP session
```