# Changing image based on selection in 2 dropdowns

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two `select` elements:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="shape" name="shape">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
  <option value="d">d</option>
  <option value="e">e</option>
  <option value="f">f</option>
</select>
```

The second one shows the sub categories of the first:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="waist" name="waist">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

These are part of a `form` that is used for other operations and names and values of these can be changed.

In my database I have images of `a-1`, `a-2`, `a-3`, `b-1`, `b-2`, `b-3`, `c-1`, `c-2`, `c-3` and so on. I have a space for images which should be updated once options have been chosen from both `select` elements.

I have read many forms but they used only one dropdown. I am bit new in javascript so can anybody help with this? You can use PHP if you want.

Comment: Can you show what you already have in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a function which is called on the `change` event of both `select` elements which concatenates the image filename and updates the `src` property of the required `img`, something like this:

```
$('select.form-control').change(function() {
    var filename = $('#shape').val() + '-' + $('#waist').val() + '.jpg';
    $('#imgToChange').prop('src', filename);
});
```

Comment: Thank for solution but sorry that i dont enough reputation to upvote.but thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the combined value of dropdowns in the format like a-2,a-3,b-1 etc.

```
document.getElementById("shape").value + "-" + document.getElementById("waist").value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a solution with jQuery (javascript) / PHP / AJAX (and don't worry, AJAX is *easy*). It will work like this:

**jQuery** - detect when both SELECT controls have been changed,
**AJAX** - a jQuery block that sends data to a back-end PHP file,
**PHP** - Receives AJAXed data and identifies the correct image (e.g. from MySQL) then builds HTML code and ECHOs it back to jQuery side,
**AJAX** - Receives PHP data via AJAX,
**jQuery** - Inside the AJAX `success` function, uses the `,html()` method to insert the new HTML into the DOM

That's the overview. Here's how it will look code-wise:

**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="shape" name="shape">
  <option value="">Options go here</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="waist" name="waist">
  <option value="">Options go here</option>
</select>

<div id="someDIV"> //DIV that will receive IMG tag </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var chg = false;
$('#shape, #waist').change(function(){
    if (!chg){
        chg=true;
    }else{
        var myimg = $('#shape').val() + $('#waist').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
             url: 'my_second_php_file.php',
            data: 'myimg=' +myimg,
            success: function(d){
                //if (d.length) alert(d);
                $('#someDIV').html(d);
            }
        }); //END AJAX
    }//end else
}); //END select.change
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    $img = $_POST['myimg'];
    //echo ($img); die();

    //$result = Do your MySQL lookup here

    $out = '
        <img src="' .$result['img']. '" class="yourImage" />
    ';
    echo $out;
?>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7xyus1a0/) that approximates how it will work. jsFiddle cannot do AJAX, so the AJAX routine is replaced by something that will demonstrate how it will look, rather than a true working example.

Here are [some simple demos of AJAX code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843) and [a brief explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025289/prevent-page-load-on-jquery-form-submit-with-none-display-button#36025530) -- copy them to your own system and experiment. Really quite simple, and xtreme useful.

[Here are some free, 10-min video mini-tuts](https://thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=61) on AJAX.

Comment: Where does the OP mention anything regarding AJAX? I think you may be over-complicating this one

Comment: No offense taken, it's tricky to balance a short comment with being courteous. That said I don't think any AJAX is needed here. Assuming the OP doesn't require any validation, the `img` element can be built directly in JS code using the values of the existing `select` elements. We need more detail from the OP in either case.

Comment: Thank you for your understanding response. OP does mention `in my database`, which is what triggered AJAX solution in my mind.

Comment: i agree this solution is nice but i will be having no idea what i am doing,but definitely  this gives us more freedom:)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below plunker as well.

https://plnkr.co/edit/1P12J0Ahl2S1m6aJ1rD0?p=preview

```
<select class="form-control" id="shape" name="shape">  
 <option value=""></option>
       <option value="a">a</option>
   <option value="b">b</option>
   <option value="c">c</option>
   <option value="d">d</option>
   <option value="e">e</option>
       <option value="f">f</option>

</select>


<select class="form-control" id="waist" name="waist">  
<option value=""></option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<button onClick="test()">Proceed</button>
```

in script.

```
var test = function(){
if($("#shape").val() != "" && $("#waist").val() != "")
{
   alert("Update");
}
else
{
   alert("select both the option");
}
};
```

here each select box has the default blank option and if user try to proceed then the value is checked and appropriate message is displayed.