# Display Image Based on 2 Dropdown Values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sql, drop-down-menu

I am hoping that you can help me out. I need to change an image based on the selection of 2 dropdown values. I have a number of image variations to show any option. I have a selection of code that I know concernates the file name of the image, but I can't seem to find a way to actually display that image. I have taken the code from a previous answer, but I can't get it to work for me - [Changing image based on selection in 2 dropdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37775237/changing-image-based-on-selection-in-2-dropdowns).

Here is the code that I am using:

```js
$('select.form-control').change(function() {
    var file = $('#shape').val() + '-' + $('#waist').val() + '.jpg';
    $('#imgToChange').prop('src', filename);
});
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="shape" name="shape">
  <option value="a">Select a country</option>
  <option value="b">Canada</option>
  <option value="c">U.S.A.</option>
</select><br>
<select class="form-control" id="waist" name="waist">
  <option value="1">Select a country</option>
  <option value="2">Canada</option>
  <option value="3">U.S.A.</option>
  <option value="4">India</option>
</select><br>
<img id="imgToChange">
```

Where am I going wrong on this one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Include the jQuery library.  console.log is a great debugging tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable you stored the image filename is different from the variable you passed as the value in for the image's `src` tag

```
$('select.form-control').change(function() {
   var filename = $('#shape').val() + '-' + $('#waist').val() + '.jpg';
   $('#imgToChange').attr('src', filename);
});
```

You can also try using the `.attr()` method in place of the `.prop()` method like i did

**Updated See code below**
**HTML**

```
<select id="select-1">
    <option value="brown-head">Brown Head</option>
    <option value="black-head">Black Head</option>
    <option value="blue-head">Blue Head</option>
</select>
<select id="select-2">
    <option value="brown-body">Brown Body</option>
    <option value="black-body">Black Body</option>
    <option value="blue-body">Blue Body</option>
</select>
<img id="imgElem" src="" alt="">
```

**JS**

```
var imageSrc;
var imgFolder = "/path/to/image/folder/"; // specify the path to the folder containing the imgs in this variable

$("select").change(function(){
    imageSrc = imgFolder + $("#select-1").val() + "-" + $("#select-2").val() + ".jpg";
    $("#imgElem").attr("src", imageSrc);
    $("p").text(imageSrc);
});
```

**UPDATED ONCE AGAIN**

This update creates the `img` tag each time an option is selected, replacing the previous `img` tag. This is to prevent the img src(undefined) error on page load.

To archive this, i added a `div` in the html to hold the `img` element, and simply change the divs html content.

**HTML UPDATED**

```
<select id="select-1">
    <option value="brown-head">Brown Head</option>
    <option value="black-head">Black Head</option>
    <option value="blue-head">Blue Head</option>
</select>
<select id="select-2">
    <option value="brown-body">Brown Body</option>
    <option value="black-body">Black Body</option>
    <option value="blue-body">Blue Body</option>
</select>

<p></p> <!--  just for debugging -->
<div class="img-wrap"></div> <!-- a div to hold the image -->
```

**JS UPDATED**

```
// specify the path to the folder containing the imgs in this variable
var imgFolder = "/path/to/image/folder/"; 

$("select").change(function(){
    var src; // variable to hold the src
    
    src = imgFolder + $("#select-1").val() + "-" + $("#select-2").val() + ".jpg";
    // append src to a p element just for debugging sake(i.e to see the change in the src)
    $("p").text(src);
    
    // create an img element with the src each time and append to the image wrap div
    $(".img-wrap").html(`<img src="${src}">`);
});
```

**UPDATED ONCE AGAIN**

To make it show the image with the default selected options both on page load and on option select, i tweaked the code again

**NEW JS CODE**

```
function getImageSrc(){
    // specify the path to the folder containing the imgs in this variable
    var imgFolder = "/path/to/image/folder/"; 

    // loop through each select element
    $("select").each(function(){
        // fire function to get src
        getSrc();
        
        // fire function to get src on change
        $(this).change(function(){
            getSrc();
        })
    });
    
    function getSrc(){
        var src; // variable to hold the src

        src = imgFolder + $("#select-1").val() + "-" + $("#select-2").val() + ".jpg";
        $("#imgElem").attr("src", src);
        // append src to a p element just for debugging sake(i.e to see the change in the src)
        $("p").text(src);

        // create a an img element with the src each time and append to the image wrap div
        $(".img-wrap").html(`<img src="${src}">`);
    }
}

// fire function on page-load
$(document).ready(function(){
    getImageSrc();
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I did miss that one. It still isn't outputting though, is it something to do with the <img id="imgToChange"> tag?

Comment: You're getting the image element correctly, i have updated my answer, check to see if it works for you.

Comment: Hi, this solution also works when it is in a Fiddle, but the moment I try open it in a browser, I get a. src(undefined) output.

Comment: Do you get the error on page load or when you click the select element

Comment: It is on page load. so it shows src(unknown) on load.

Comment: I'm including these libraries:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>/
Are these the only ones needed

Comment: The error doesnt have anything to do with the scripts you're loading into your webpage

Comment: As for the src(unknown) error, the browser expects the img tag to come with a non-empty src attribute, so a possible fix would be to create the img tag and append it to the body when the use selects an option

Comment: That makes sense, but my knowledge here is lacking. How would I do that? It is so strange that in a Fiddle it works perfectly, but in application it doesn't. Would I be creating the img tag in the JQuery?

Comment: This is amazing! I am going to mark this as the correct answer. Question though, and I am hoping you can quickly answer. Is there a way that when the page loads the first selection variable shows the associated image?

Comment: I've made another update to my answer, were i implemented that. Sorry I couldn't reply quick, it was already very late in the midnight. Had to go to bed

Comment: Thank you so much!! You have been a lifesaver. I hope that this thread gets more views along the way as I think it is an important topic with very little explanation on the web!

Answer (score 0):

Your variable name should be **filename** not just file because that's what you're using in your code. Here's what you need.

```
$('select.form-control').change(function() {
   var filename = $('#shape').val() + '-' + $('#waist').val() + '.jpg';
   $('#imgToChange').prop('src', filename);
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you're pulling your images from a folder **img** then you need to do this:

```
$('#imgToChange').prop('src', 'img/'+filename);
```

Comment: @AndrewRoyal if it helped you please accept this answer as the correct one? Thanks

Comment: I am still struggling to get the image to output, is it something to do with my <img id="imgToChange"> tag?

Comment: @AndrewRoyal no, using <img id="imgToChange"> is perfectly fine. Basically, every time you select a value from one of those dropdowns the value of src attribute gets updated. For example: <img id="imgToChange" src="a-1"> . Where are you pulling the images from? Are they coming from a folder? if yes, what's the folder name?

Comment: @AndrewRoyal if you're pulling your images from a folder then make sure to have the correct path to the src attribute

Comment: I am pulling from a local folder img so I'm assuming i replace 'src' with 'img/' in the prop ststement. Sorry my JQuery is limited. Ultimately the folder will be from uploads in a WordPress install

Comment: @AndrewRoyal ok, if you're pulling your images from a folder called img then do this: $('#imgToChange').prop('src', 'img/'+filename);  that should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks @HenryDev. If I put it in a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/36uh2xjg/ it works perfectly, but if I run it in Chrome no dice. It won't fill in the src field.

Comment: @AndrewRoyal the answer you should just fine in any browser. That's one of the nicest things about jQuery